# Test for an empty list comprehension in if/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

Is it possible to reduce the amount of lines in the method `find_indexes` to just 1 line using an if/else statement like as seen in the return statement?

```
def find_indexes(sentence, target):
    indexes = [index for index, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x]

    return indexes if indexes else False

target = 'dont'
sentence = 'we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont'

print(find_indexes(sentence, target))
>> [1, 6, 13]
print(find_indexes(sentence, 'johndoe'))
>> False
```

I'm looking to change the method to something like this, without the need to write the comprehension twice:

```
def find_indexes(sentence, target):
    return [index for index, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x] \ 
       if [index for index, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x] else False
```

> Write a procedure that takes a string of words separated by spaces
> (assume no punctuation or capitalization), together with a ”target”
> word, and shows the position of the target word in the string of
> words.
>
> For example, if the string is:
>
> we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont
>
> and the target is the word:
>
> ”dont”
>
> then your procedure should return the list 1, 6, 13 because ”dont” appears
> at the 1st, 6th, and 13th position in the string. (We start counting
> positions of words in the string from 0.) Your procedure should return
> False if the target word doesn’t appear in the string

Comment: `return [index for index, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x] or False`

Comment: Note: Explicitly returning `False` is fairly pointless. Just return the listcomp itself; if it's empty, it will behave as a falsy value, and 99% of the time, that's fine (or better than fine, since it still acts like a sequence, so you can blindly do a `for` loop over the result and it will simply not do anything). It's generally not Pythonic to insist on actual `True`/`False` values, just allow implicit truthiness testing to do its thing.

Comment: Why do you think `False` is a better return value than `[]`? An empty list will be treated as `False` in any context where you should be using a Boolean value (and I'm explicitly counting `foo == False` as something you should *not* be doing).

Comment: +1 to the comments above, if your function should `return` a `list` let it always `return` one, not a mixture of `list`s and `bool`s

Comment: It was in the question I was supplying the answer for that asked for it to be False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can short-circuit with `or`:

```
def find_indexes(sentence, target):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x] or False
```

Answer (score 4):

Just return the empty list if there are no matches found.

```
def find_indexes(sentence, target):
    return [index for index, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x]

indices = find_indexes("hi there bob", "bob")
if not indices:
    print("No matches found")
else:
    for i in indices:
        print("Found match at {}".format(i))
```

Comment: Indeed. I recognized it as the word "is", but didn't take the next step to remembering it is a keyword.

Answer (score 3):

```
return [...] or False
```

The `or` operator returns one of its operands; the first if the first is truthy, otherwise the second.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `False` isn't only pointless, it makes the code larger and more brittle.

Every time you use the original `find_indexes` function, you need to check if it's a boolean or a list. Otherwise, your code might raise a `TypeError` if no index is found:

```
def find_indexes(sentence, target):
    indices = [index for index, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if target == x]
    return indices if indices else False

sentence = 'we dont need no education we dont need no thought control no we dont'

for index in find_indexes(sentence, "not_found"):
    print(index)
```

It throws:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

As suggested by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), simply return an empty list if no index is found : an empty list is falsey in Python anyway. You need one line less in your function and in every susequent call.

Finally, since Python is a dynamic language, it's really important to use adequate function names in order to write readable code. If your function is called `find_indexes`, it should return an iterable. If it's called `is_a_substring`, then it should return a boolean.